# Strange behavior of paste

Tags: text-processing, paste

I am experiencing some strange behavior of the paste tool. For some reason it appears to not do it's job on two specific files, but I cannot reproduce that behavior with other files.

The first file:

```
$ cat file1
20.623 40.276 -1.999 -1031 127 141 154
20.362 40.375 -2.239 -941 130 141 159
20.36 40.376 -2.402 -1083 139 151 165
20.374 40.367 -2.405 -1122 131 147 163
20.372 40.366 -2.405 -1165 132 145 161
20.375 40.364 -2.404 -1036 133 149 165
20.358 40.371 -2.405 -1137 139 151 165
20.359 40.374 -2.404 -1086 139 151 165
20.354 40.375 -2.404 -1106 139 148 163
20.356 40.374 -2.404 -1059 139 151 165
```

The second file:

```
$ cat file2
-1
-1
2
-1
-1
-1
-1
2
2
2
```

Now paste does what I expect it to do after the following call:

```
$ paste file2 file1
-1  20.623 40.276 -1.999 -1031 127 141 154
-1  20.362 40.375 -2.239 -941 130 141 159
2   20.36 40.376 -2.402 -1083 139 151 165
-1  20.374 40.367 -2.405 -1122 131 147 163
-1  20.372 40.366 -2.405 -1165 132 145 161
-1  20.375 40.364 -2.404 -1036 133 149 165
-1  20.358 40.371 -2.405 -1137 139 151 165
2   20.359 40.374 -2.404 -1086 139 151 165
2   20.354 40.375 -2.404 -1106 139 148 163
2   20.356 40.374 -2.404 -1059 139 151 165
```

However, when switching the arguments, the produced lines are created by somehow merging the lines instead of concatenating them:

```
$ paste file1 file2
20.623 4-1276 -1.999 -1031 127 141 154
20.362 4-1375 -2.239 -941 130 141 159
20.36 402376 -2.402 -1083 139 151 165
20.374 4-1367 -2.405 -1122 131 147 163
20.372 4-1366 -2.405 -1165 132 145 161
20.375 4-1364 -2.404 -1036 133 149 165
20.358 4-1371 -2.405 -1137 139 151 165
20.359 42.374 -2.404 -1086 139 151 165
20.354 42.375 -2.404 -1106 139 148 163
20.356 42.374 -2.404 -1059 139 151 165
```

Note that the second numbers are messed up. I find it even stranger that paste does what I would expect in the following:

```
$ cat test1
5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6
$ cat test2
-2
-7
$ paste test2 test1
-2  5 5 5 5
-7  6 6 6 6
$ paste test1 test2
5 5 5 5 -2
6 6 6 6 -7
```

The man page couldn't help me save my problems. Any explanations and help for the task I try to achieve?

Comment: Windows-style (CR-LF) line endings maybe?

Comment: This was closed as off topic because it was "unlikely to help future readers".  It shouldnt be closed, because I found it hugely helpful.  Clearly issues with `paste` due to Windows-style line endings are a common failure mode, and not "a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly [goes] away on its own"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed the windows line-endings that caused this behavior. After running

```
sed $'s/\r//' -i file1
```

To replace them, paste worked as expected. Thanks to steeldriver for pointing me into the right direction. Another solution is using

```
dos2unix file1
```